# Word stemming in R

Tags: r, text-mining, stemming

I am working on a text mining project and trying to clean the text - words in singular/plural forms, verbs in different tenses and misspelling words. My sample looks like this:

```
test <- c("apple","apples","wife","wives","win","won","winning","winner","orange","oranges","orenge")
```

I tried to use the wordStem function in SnowballC package. However the results are wrong:

```
"appl"   "appl"   "wife"   "wive"   "win"    "won"    "win"    "winner" "orang"  "orang"  "oreng"
```

What I would like to see is:

```
"apple"   "apple"   "wife"   "wife"   "win"    "win"    "win"    "winner" "orange"  "orange"  "orange"
```

Comment: You might want to look into the `stemCompletion` function in the tm package.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the results?  For many applications of text analysis, it's sufficient that two different forms of a word map to the same stem, without that stem needing to be the actual English root word.  In particular, the function you're calling uses a version of Dr. Martin Porter's popular stemming algorithm, which doesn't try to find the actual English root.  The results aren't "wrong" -- it's doing what it was designed to do, just not what you were expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just how the Porter Stemmer works. The reason for this is that it allows fairly simple rules to create the stems without having to store a large English vocabulary.   For example, I think that you would not like that both `change` and `changing` go to `chang`. It seems more natural that they should both stem to `change`. So would you make a rule that if you take `ing` off the end of a word, you should add back `e` to get the stem? Then what would happen with `clang` and `clanging`? The Porter Stemmer gives `clang`. Adding `e` would give the non-word `clange`. Either you use simple processing rules that sometimes create stems that are not words, *or* you must include a large vocabulary and have more complex rules that depend on what the words are. The Porter Stemmer uses the simple rules method.